# Tornar a seleção do Global na Aplicação

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Queria saber como faço pra tornar a seleção do ano global na aplicação e trabalhar com os dados apenas com o ano selecionado. Tenho que fazer o ManagedBean ser ApplicationScope? Como faço pra navegar na aplicação e não perde-lo no select.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
insira o código aqui
```

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class GestaoAnoSelecaoGlobal implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Inject
private AnoSelecaos sisuAnoSelecaos;

private List<AnoSelecao> listaSisuAnoSelecaos = new ArrayList<>();

private AnoSelecao sisuAnoSelecao = new AnoSelecao();

public void todosSisuAnoSelecaos() {
    listaSisuAnoSelecaos = sisuAnoSelecaos.todas();
    System.out.println(listaSisuAnoSelecaos.size());
}

public List<AnoSelecao> getListaSisuAnoSelecaos() {
    return listaSisuAnoSelecaos;
}

public AnoSelecao getSisuAnoSelecao() {
    return sisuAnoSelecao;
}

public void setSisuAnoSelecao(AnoSelecao sisuAnoSelecao) {
    this.sisuAnoSelecao = sisuAnoSelecao;
}
```

}

No xhml

```
        <f:selectItems value="#{gestaoAnoSelecaoGlobal.listaSisuAnoSelecaos}"
            var="anoSelecao" itemValue="#{anoSelecao}"  itemLabel="#{anoSelecao.anoSelecao}" />             
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Com esse escopo não carrega a lista, mas usando @ViewScoped funciona normalmente. Você já teve esse problema?

Comment: Tente usar @SessionScoped que uma vez escolhido ao logar, o valor irá ficar na sessão.

Comment: Fiz o que me ajudou e não carrega as informações na SelectOneMenu. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Crie a classe init() anotando @PostConstruct e chame o método para carregar as informações, ela será chamada na primeira criação da tela.